# Adequate software to plot grids, numerical stencils...

Tags: numerical-methods, math-software

Do you know any software (online or not) easy to understand and appropriate to create this kind of plots?

[image: 1]

I would like the image to be vectorized, can write subindices, arrows, dots and so on to explain numerical stencils and grids.

Comment: That graphic looks like it was created using [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/), which creates high-quality graphics for TeX documents. If the learning curve is too steep there and you want something that isn't TeX-based, what operating system will you be using?

Comment: @pjs36 Windows 7